# Ui router issues with accessing state in state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a home page with a classes section. I have a navbar with a classes link. If you are on the page , clicking the link should scroll down to the classes section. If you are on another page, clicking the link should bring you back to the home page and then scroll to the classes section. 
I am having issues with the way I handle my state - for now if I am on another page my OnEnter function blocks by saying Cannot 'read property 'top' of undefined'. This being said, I am probably mo writing my states properly.

```
    $stateProvider
 .state('home', {
  url : '/',
  templateUrl:'components/home/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
 .state('classes', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl:'components/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    onEnter: function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#classes").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
})
```

Comment: I solved it but doing placing a if statement in the onEnter function checking  for the #classes DOM element and using setimeout if #classes is not there but it cannot be best practices - please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you enter the state, the view (HTML) might not yet be loaded and added to the DOM. You may fix the issue with `viewContentLoaded` event. See:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events

I think you can also use ui-router's own `autoscroll` directive to achieve the same effect: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#autoscroll